# Set variable with dynamic name in trigger (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, trigger

I need to create some kind of generic trigger that will alter value of columns which names are stored in another table. So basically I wonder if is possible to do something like this:

```
delimiter ;;

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE columnName VARCHAR(20);
    SET columnName = 'my_column';
    SET NEW.{columnName} = 'my value'; -- pseudo-code
END;;


delimiter ;
```

Comment: Yes you can use but first do declare a variable and then use for example   DECLARE v_pDB VARCHAR(20);    
  Set v_pDB = DATABASE();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve with this, you may be out of luck.

First of all, names cannot be parametrised in MySQL otherwise than using a prepared statement.

– So, can we use a prepared statement here?

No. Prepared statements are not allowed in triggers, [according to the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

> SQL syntax for prepared statements can be used within stored procedures, but not in stored functions or triggers.

– All right, prepared statements can be used in stored procedures. Can we create a stored procedure that would use a prepared statement to do the job, and call the procedure from the trigger?

Nope. A stored procedure cannot reference NEW and OLD columns – those namespaces are available only in triggers.

The only option appears to be an `IF ... ELSEIF ...` statement comparing `columnName` against a *fixed* set of names and assigning values to corresponding columns.

```
IF columnName = 'colname1' THEN
   SET NEW.colname1 = '...';
ELSEIF columnName = 'colname2' THEN
   SET NEW.colname2 = '...';
ELSEIF
   ...
END IF;
```

This method will not work if you are trying to include non-existent names (in order to cover columns that might be added later, for instance) in the checkings. And, of course, this method will just be unsuitable for you if you are trying to stipulate for *unknown* names.

But then, perhaps, what you are trying to do is not what you should be doing to begin with. Perhaps, you should revisit your *schema* and consider a different data model (at least for some portion of your data), like [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You dynamically build the query.

- Use `CONCAT` to construct the SQL to include the column name provided;
- `PREPARE` it`;
- `EXECUTE` it;
- `DEALLOCATE`

Comment: Hi Rick, as trigger will not allow prepare statements and we can use stored procedure suppose want to pass DB name as variable in a query but still we can't call that stored procedure from trigger as trigger still not allowed prepare statements even in stored procedure...any trick so that we can achieve it.

Comment: You have encountered one of many limitations in Triggers, FKs, etc.  I prefer to do all "side effects" in my code, and not try to shoehorn them into Triggers and FKs.

Comment: First of all thanks for your attention on it..I complete agree with you and I have same views and already suggested to our dev team to take care this part in code just after insert statement as there are limitation as well drawback of triggers but they are insisting to achieve by trigger...even I have got a solution by putting different DB code under different if conditions as in our case there are limited DB so we can achieve it....but I want to know for my knowledge also if there is some better trick for it.

Comment: My preferred technique is to have a "database layer".  The application calls a routine in it saying "Here; put this into the database".  The layer then knows to do an `INSERT` here, `UPDATE` there, etc. to achieve the goal.  That is, it is translating the 'simple' request into all the 'side effects' that are required for the schema as it is designed.  Bonus:  If the schema changes, only the 'layer' need to be modified.